# Laravel paginate() on custom static functions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-paginate

I want to paginate a custom static function.

When using Eloquent goes like this `People::paginate(5);` and paginates the results.

I need to do the same for this static function `People::getOwners();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what is going on inside `getOwners()`, you could turn it into a query scope. On your `People` model, add the function:

```
public function scopeGetOwners($query) {
    // $query->where(...);
    // $query->orderBy(...);
    // etc.

    $return $query;
}
```

Now, `getOwners()` is treated like any other query scope modifier (e.g. where, orderBy, etc.):

```
People::getOwners()->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do your query and pagination in the function, like this:

```
public function getOwners() {
    return self::query()->paginate(5); 
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, unfortunately i cannot use it like this cause i'm using the same function without pagination!